# How to tokenize a string in C++ (like ply.lex in Python)?

Tags: python, c++, parsing, lexer, ply

How do I easily tokenize a document or string using C++?
I'm familiar with `ply.lex` module in Python but I couldn't find anything for C++. Is there a C++ library which can make use of `lex` and `yacc`? Or is there another better library or way of doing this easily?

Comment: lex generates C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

[`flex`](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/#flex) and [`lex`](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/#lex) are the equivalent of `ply.lex`. Example of `flex`:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%option noyywrap

%%
"+"               { puts("token: +"); }
"-"               { puts("token: -"); }
[0-9]+            { printf("token: %s\n", yytext); }
" "               { /* empty */ }
[\n|\r\n\t]       { /* empty */ }
.                 { fprintf(stderr, "Tokenizing error: synatx error '%c'\n", *yytext);
                    yyterminate(); }
%%

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  yylex();
  return 0;
}
```

compiling:

```
> flex example.l
> gcc -Wall lex.yy.c -o lex
> lex
100 - 2 + 34
token: 100
token: -
token: 2
token: +
token: 34
>
```